# Arithmetic sequence in Ruby using #reduce

Tags: ruby

The question is simple: implement an arithmetic sequence algorithm with params (first,n,c) where first is the first number in the sequence, n is the nth index in the sequence, and c is the addition number for the sequence. This is what I've done but so far it's giving me wrong answers.

EDIT: found solution, below

```
def nthterm(first, n, c)
 (1..n).reduce(first){|memo, x| memo += c}
end



Test.assert_equals(nthterm(1, 2, 3), 7)
Test.assert_equals(nthterm(2, 2, 2), 6)
Test.assert_equals(nthterm(-50, 10, 20), 150)
```

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help!

Comment: Your description seems off, `c` appears to be a number, not an operator.

Comment: youre right I will change the description. I will also post the solution I was trying to go for for posterity

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions to include the answer. Instead you should post them as a answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def nthterm(first, n, c)
  (1..n).reduce([first]){|memo| memo << memo[-1] + c}
end
```

> nthterm(1, 10, 20)
>   ==> 
>   [1, 21, 41, 61, 81, 101, 121, 141, 161, 181, 201]

Answer (score 0):

```
def nthterm(first, n, c)
   first + n * c 
end
```

A lot simpler and a lot more efficient than looping `c` times which is what you are implicitely doing through reduce.